# Crack Unknown Encryption

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis

I was challenged by a friend to decrypt a piece of text that was somehow encrypted. The encrypted text is the following:

```
LY3IoH5HWSnp9-efCfOH3jqmoGaXdURF4YAKgIh2KotjHLyFbLBgXr0uzPu1-K0sEGUogoTduKF1_eklAVzOlEfziqIvqtlhZeJPF8H2ER0jLc25jPC8_AOPlAvTHKdA8BVPFPwu1Ldaul4IPBVWJSJc5fhTGJAjfSL2Rum-pW8VCSJwnB3LZR1ACVR0KN0HCv7hIKJ88TNUc4hHk5g4sstPxdeQqUIu7GjY1C8M3jl4EMo9yqHoo1Mj7Q4vxPWGUM_OhMR46s772EpqNXk62pldQomWovdvB2pYh_srTFYM0u5MMQd5Z1nUUCwA--QiQX5cJmSxw7U8lVo78K6Qm4oGirfFJVlYIzPClCNziLewhEXvaKv1KmDtnUi03lAXQMuHjQqfMzMLJibXrw
```

How would one go about solving this type of puzzle?

Comment: I guess I would ask for help on Security.SE. Oh wait...

Comment: at that lenght, sure it's not an OTP? Does *somehow encrypted* mean that the principle is that there is a key, a message and a algorithm?

Comment: Looks like a good question for http://crypto.stackexchange.com/ (even though that's still in beta). Flagged as such.

Comment: Also, did you try searching for parts of it yet? https://www.google.nl/search?q=LY3IoH5HWSnp9 Could very well be your friend just used a string found somewhere (perhaps a GUID) to pull your leg.

Comment: @SQB - it is too long to be a GUID.  It is not a good question for SE or Crypto.  It is too broad to discuss general decryption of an unknown algorithm and is off topic on either site.  It does appear that it is an identifying token rather than an encrypted message though from those search results.

Comment: @AJHenderson Thanks. I wasn't aware of the scope of the Crypto Stack; my reaction should be read as "hey, isn't there a Cryptp Stack somewhere?"

Comment: @SQB - If it wasn't too broad, it would probably be on topic there.  But this question is an entire field of study, not a Q/A topic.  "How do I break generic encryption?" takes multiple text books and college classes, not a several paragraph answer.

Comment: Your options are captured by [this comic](http://xkcd.com/538/). Personally I would choose the one on the right. You know where your friend lives, right?

Comment: @SQB I'm a mod on crypto. This sort of question would be [off-topic](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/100/do-we-want-challenge-analyse-this-questions-and-if-so-what-constraints-if-any) there. We don't accept request to analyze or decrypt data for someone.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer : you don't.

One of the main rules about encryption is that the security mustn't rely on the algorithm staying secret. This is because this information can always leak in some way : reverse-engineering, people talking too much... However, in this case "security through obscurity" happens to be pretty solid.

With great knowledge about cryptography, and more likely if the encryption used is weak, you *might* be able to notice some pattern or other information that narrows down the potential encryption algorithms. But decoding this string without any other information seems pretty difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [frequency analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis) could be a first step.
But it will only help you with simple [substitution ciphers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher).